# iOS unit test with core data/MagicalRecord unexpected behavior

Tags: ios, core-data, magicalrecord

I got the following test code.

```
@interface SubscriberTest : XCTestCase

@end

@implementation SubscriberTest

- (void)setUp
{
    [super setUp];
    [MagicalRecord setDefaultModelFromClass:[self class]];
    [MagicalRecord setupCoreDataStackWithInMemoryStore];

}


- (void)tearDown
{
    [super tearDown];
    [MagicalRecord cleanUp];
}

- (void)testParseSubscriberWithEvents
{
   NSEntityDescription *pDesc = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Subscriber"
                                         inManagedObjectContext:[NSManagedObjectContext MR_defaultContext]];
   XCTAssertNotNil(pDesc);


- (void)testParseSubscriberWithReviews
{
   NSEntityDescription *pDesc = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Subscriber"
                                         inManagedObjectContext:[NSManagedObjectContext MR_defaultContext]];
    XCTAssertNotNil(pDesc);

}
```

@end

I don't understand why the first test always succeed and the second always fail..
it's like each test is creating is own `ManagedObjectContext`, but the second is not aware of my entity...
In fact this code is used to test import of json data. I debugged MagicalRecord's code to see that the problem comes from the method

```
[NSEntityDescription entityForName: inManagedObjectContext:]
```

Which is returning nil in the second test...

I tried to comment the first test, the second test worked! but if they are two test the second fails each time...

For info i'm using `MagicalRecord` 2.3.0.beta (because of some bugs in 2.2 importFromObject method...)
Any help and explanation would be much appreciated!

Comment: Can you put a project somewhere that reproduces the issue - I've just created a minimal project with this set up and it works fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like after the first test -tearDown destroys CoreData stack, for some reason next time -setUp is called MagicalRecord doesn't correctly initialize Core Data stack (second time context is nil as you found) which results in failing your second test. I found that if you setup core data stack once (you can achieve this by calling dispatch_once in -setUp) and call [Subscriber MR_truncateAll] in -tearDown it does work.